# Comma(s) when using: "As of January 2018" at end of sentence

Tags: commas, writing-style, dates

Here is a sentence for you:

> *The Amiga Computer Corporation has finally closed its doors
>   permanently as of January 2018.*

Should the comma(s) be placed like this:

> The Amiga Computer Corporation has finally closed its doors
>   permanently, as of January 2018.

OR

> The Amiga Computer Corporation has finally closed its doors
>   permanently, as of January, 2018.

OR

... No commas used at all?

Comment: It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to include either or both of those commas. Personally I'd use neither, but I have to say the first looks less "stuffy, awkward" than the second - so if you were determined to include at least one, keep the first. I can't be bothered to find anything to back me up, but I'm pretty sure the modern trend is towards reduced comma use (and most other punctuation marks) unless it's necessary to help the reader parse the text. Which isn't the case in your context.

Comment: I agree with @ FumbleFingers but as a side issue am wondering if you shouldn't have used the future tense "will finally close its doors", since January 2018 has not yet happened. At least it hasn't happened where I live!

Answer (score 1):

The rule is that no comma is required between a month and a year if there is no number between them. (This rule is widely cited. See, e.g.: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/.)

When, as in your example, a date is at the end of a sentence, no comma is required before the date.  (See, e.g. grammartips.homestead.com; “When to Use Commas with Dates”)

The sentence is, in any case, a bit awkward. The use of the past perfect (has...closed) indicates a completed action in the past while the date, January 2018, is still in the future.  If the date is in the future the sentence should read: "The Amiga Computer Corporation will finally close its doors permanently (note spelling) in January 2018."   If the closing occurred  in the past: "The Amiga Computer Corporation finally closed its doors permanently in January 2017."
The use of "as of" is also problematic. It is best employed to indicate the effective date of an action or document which has been or will be executed at some different time (or times, in the case of multiple actors).  When this nuance is not present, "as of" should be eschewed in favor of "on" or "in".  See Garner's Modern English Language, Page 75.